# Llamar variable de un evento clic

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

¿Es posible llamar la variable de un evento clic, en otro evento clic?

Si es posible... ¿Cómo lo hago?

Vera, he creado un evento y dentro de este he hecho botones dinámicamente, les he asignado el mismo evento para que hagan el mismo proceso y traigan diferentes valores respecto a su nombre.

Lo que quiero intentar es lo siguiente:

Aquí es donde creo los botones y les asigno un evento.

```
protected void Unnamed1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Pop", "showAndHide();", true);

            Button Btn_clic = (Button)sender;
            var name = Btn_clic.Text;

            List.ListUsers listArea = new List.ListUsers();
            List<Data.Area> Area = listArea.AreaList();

            List<Data.Area> ListOfEquiposOk = Area.Where(x => x.AREA == name && x.STANDBY == 0).ToList();

            List<Button> Botones = new List<Button>();

            var TeamFCH = ListOfEquiposOk.Select(x => x.TEAM).Distinct().ToList();

            foreach (var team in TeamFCH)
            {
                Button newButton = new Button();
                newButton.CommandName = "Btn" + Convert.ToString(team);
                newButton.ID = "Btn_" + Convert.ToString(team);
                newButton.Text = team;
                newButton.Click += new EventHandler(Info_Click);

                newButton.OnClientClick = "return ModalGood();";
                Botones.Add(newButton);

                GoodPanel.Controls.Add(newButton);
                newButton.CssClass = "btn-primary outline separate";
            }
        }
```

Y aquí es donde quiero mandar a llamar la variable name anteriormente declarada para poder llenar el GridView

```
protected void Info_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button Btnclick = (Button)sender;
            var team = Btnclick.Text;

            List.ListUsers listArea = new List.ListUsers();
            List<Data.Area> Tools = listArea.AreaList();

            List<Data.Area> ListOfToolsOk = Tools.Where(x => x.AREA == name && x.TEAM == team && x.STANDBY == 0).ToList();
                                                                        ^
                                                                        |
                                                                Variable a llamar


            //var ToolArea = ListOfToolsOk.Select(x => x.TEAM)
            Grv_Eng.DataSource = ListOfToolsOk;
            Grv_Eng.DataBind();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usa un hiddenfield:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" />
```

Al cual le asignas un valor en la propiedad value:

```
Hiddenfield1.value = Btn_clic.Text;
```

También puedes usar variables de sesión:

```
session["variable"]= Btn_clic.Text;
string strBtn = (string)session["variable"];
```

Con las variables de sesión considera que después de un tiempo, estas expiran y pierden el valor almacenado.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que intentas hacer no es posible ya que la variable esta creada de manera local en el evento click del primer boton y solo la puedes usar en ese ambito. Si quieres almacenar datos asociados a un button es mejor usar la propiedad tag que te deja almacenar datos del tipo object.

Comment: tendras alguna referencia para conocer mas del tema?

Comment: Que tal Maanfred, he intando usar la propiedad tag con lo que he leido pero no he llegado a un logro, me podrias indicar como usar esta propiedad?